# How to clean the excess file in iphone?

Tags: ios, file

I want to add a function which clean the excess file in iphone to my app. But I can't find the api to implement it.Could you tell me? Thank you!

I'm sorry.I don't have described my problem exactly.I want to clear excess file on disk.The excess file is all of the temporary file in the iphone device.The function is like iClean(https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/iclean-remove-clean-all-deleted/id661800424?l=en&mt=8).

Comment: The excess file? You mean any file on disk you no longer want?

Comment: Have you tried in the setting pannel if you can delete de file from here?

Comment: You want to delete files from your app ? or from iPhone in general ?

Comment: Yes, It is any file on disk I no longer want.

Comment: Then can you make it more clear in the question description that you are talking about files that you no longer want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**High-level Concept:**

You may want to take a look at improving file system performance by managing the file cache [(File System Performance)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/FileSystem/Articles/FilePerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001987-CJBHIIJA). Generally speaking the fewer times you modify the file system the better. You will also only be able to edit the files you produce within your own application. Even more important will be for you to read the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672).

Within the guide you will find sample code that will help you achieve your goal specific to your particular use-case (see example below):

Listing 2-4  Enumerating the contents of a directory

```
NSURL *directoryURL = <#An NSURL object that contains a reference to a directory#>;

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    NSURLIsDirectoryKey, NSURLIsPackageKey, NSURLLocalizedNameKey, nil];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                     enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL
                                     includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                     options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants |
                                              NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles)
                                     errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                                         // Handle the error.
                                         // Return YES if the enumeration should continue after the error.
                                         return <#YES or NO#>;
                                     }];

for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {

    // Error-checking is omitted for clarity.

    NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
    [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:NULL];

    if ([isDirectory boolValue]) {

        NSString *localizedName = nil;
        [url getResourceValue:&localizedName forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:NULL];

        NSNumber *isPackage = nil;
        [url getResourceValue:&isPackage forKey:NSURLIsPackageKey error:NULL];

        if ([isPackage boolValue]) {
            NSLog(@"Package at %@", localizedName);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Directory at %@", localizedName);
        }
    }
}
```

OR a shorter way...

Listing 2-6  Retrieving the list of items in a directory all at once

```
NSURL *url = <#A URL for a directory#>;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *properties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSURLLocalizedNameKey,
                          NSURLCreationDateKey, NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey, nil];

NSArray *array = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                   contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:url
                   includingPropertiesForKeys:properties
                   options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles)
                   error:&error];
if (array == nil) {
    // Handle the error
}
```

**What to do next:**

Once you have information in an array you could look at using NSPredicate to search for specific items and use the NSFileManager to delete the actual files. There are many permutations for combining the available APIs, which is why more information may be required for a more complete solution. The best answer may be for you to start with the documentation above and try out some of the APIs and then come back with more specific questions. Please consider accepting this answer if it meets your immediate needs.